# ERD diagram for a market

Tags: sql, database, diagram, erd

I have a requirement on a project and I have to make an erd diagram for a market. I have the following text:

Michael is going to the market and wants to buy some groceries: vegetables(tomatoes and cucumbers), fruits(apples and oranges), some drinks and meal.

Based on this text I have to create the ERD diagram and I am stuck, is look like I forgot anything about ERD in this moment. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to identify the 'entities' like:

- categories (vegetables, fruits)
- products (tomatoes, cucumbers, apples, oranges) with respect to category_id as foreign key

Then define their attributes and keys

- define all keys (primary key, foreign key)
- all attributes of entities

Then define relations between all these entities

- 1 to 1 (one product belongs to one category)
- 1 to many (one product belongs to many categories)
- many to many  (many products belong to many categories)

By following these steps, I am sure you will get ERD.